# Setup for high volume of database writing

Tags: python, django, database-design, amazon-web-services

I am researching a project that would require hundreds of database writes per a minute. I have never dealt with this level of data writes before and I am looking for good scalable techniques and technologies.

I am a comfortable python developer with experience in django and sql alchemy. I am thinking I will build the data interface on django, but I don't think that it is a good idea to go through the orm to do the amount of data writes I will require. I am definitely open to learning new technologies.

The solution will live on Amazon web services, so I have access to all their tools. Ultimately I am looking for advice on database selection, data writing techniques, and any other needs I may have that I do not realize.

Any advice on where to start?

Thanks,
CG

Comment: Can you give us more information about your actual use pattern?  If you're just writing, and never need to read, then `/dev/null` is the database of choice...

Comment: I will be keeping track of data such as where a widget is running and how many times, I would use urchin or some other tracking tool but eventually I want to be able to take advantage of the data for descision making reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the trends, in other words, enter the world of NOSQL. Some technologies that are worthy include [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [redis](http://redis.io). They are really fast, scalable, and with decent python drivers. For example, mongodb plays really nice with django, and has many common things with traditional SQL, like MySQL. On the other hand, redis has more "primitive" data structures but is superior in terms of speed (which of course depends somehow on the drivers). Using any of them ( or both, it's a clever idea for something glorious ) you are free ( and sometimes enforced ) to write your own "low-level" logic to accomplish your needs.

Comment: I wouldn't say "plays really nice" it works? isn't there still a lack of support for admin using mongo? also requires to sacrifice some orm functionalitY?

Comment: There is always a trade-off. I strongly believe that the community is in turmoil, so some minor drawbacks (due to immaturity) are soon to be fixed. Of course you can't have ( for the moment ) admin support with mongo. And yes, you have to write some custom orm-like client code, but you'll be rewarded in terms of speed. It really depends on the application.

Comment: I am not married to using the admin to get at this data. I am however needing to be able to get at it through the template code. I was considering a no sql option, I am curious if there is a particular package that simplifies the database queries in a manner similar to django's orm. Also would you recommend working directly with the database for writes or should I look at a plugin to assist with this. Any expereince with python lazyboy?

Comment: No experience with lazyboy, but mongoengine is a nice orm (or drm, better) for django. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You should actually be okay with low hundreds of writes per minute through SQLAlchemy (thats only a couple a second); if you're talking more like a thousand a minute, yeah that might be problematic.

What kind of data do you have?  If it's fairly flat (few tables, few relations), you might want to investigate a non-relational database such as CouchDB or Mongo.  If you want to use SQL, I strongly reccommend PostgreSQL, it seems to deal with large databases and frequent writes a lot better than MySQL.

It also depends how complex the data is that you're inserting.

I think unfortunately, you're going to just have to try a couple things and run benchmarks, as each situation is different and query optimizers are basically magic.

Comment: I will be starting with hundreds per a minute, but I would like ultimate scalability in the future. The data is going to be very straight forward at first just storing what is happening where. I will eventually be using it to make contextual suggestions.

Comment: This would probably be a good thing to test, for all I know SQLAlchemy is fine at 2K/minute... I just don't have personal experience with more than maybe 10/second.

Comment: As you can't foretell the future exactly, start with what you know and works for now, which is alchemy. SQL stores are much better to explore using ad hoc queries too. But keep the alchemy behind some API abstraction, so you can replace it later. See my response about using a queue and threads.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a few hundred writes you still can do with a relational DB. I'd pick PostgreSQL (8.0+),
which has a separate background writer process. It also has tuneable serialization levels so you
can enable some tradeoffs between speed and strict ACID compliance, some even at transaction level.

Postgres is well documented, but it assumes some deeper understanding of SQL and relational DB theory to fully understand and make the most of it.

The alternative would be new fangled "NO-SQL" system, which can probably scale even better, but at the cost of buying into a very different technology system.

Any way, if you are using python and it is not 100% critical to lose writes on shutdown or power loss, and you need a low latency, use a threadsafe Queue.Queue and worker threads to decouple the writes from your main application thread(s).